# Change the color of the background for each card composable in a lazy list - Jetpack Compose, Android

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an app that basically allows the user to search through a list of card composables, each with a heading and a body of text. My question is about changing the color of the background for each card to be a different color from a list of colors I have created. I somehow need to iterate through the list of colors and pass a different color each time and I'm not sure how I do that. Here is some code:

```
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = matte_black)
        ) {
            val list = if (searching) searchResults else allReadings
            list.value.let { list ->
                items(list.size) { i ->
                    val reading = list[i]
                    ReadingItem(reading, **TODO("Add Color")**)
                }
            }


        }
```

and the composable ReadingItem:

```
fun ReadingItem(
    reading: ReadingData,
    **color : Color**
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val resources = context.resources
    val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density
    val spacing = 16.dp
    val scroll = rememberScrollState()

    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        backgroundColor = color, TODO("This is where i would like the color to iterate through the list")
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.width(screenWidth.dp - (spacing * 2)),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
            Text(
                text = reading.title,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = milk_white,
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            )
            //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = reading.reading,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(
                        state = scroll),
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = milk_white,
                    fontSize = 16.sp
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, the list of colors:

```
fun getColors() : List<Color> {
    return listOf(
        flame_red, orange, ucla_gold, green, tropaz, calypso, plum
    )
}
```

If anyone has any advice it would be very appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should give a basic idea.

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun ColourCards() {
    val colors = listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Magenta, Color.Gray, Color.Cyan)
    LazyColumn {
        items(40) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(
                        horizontal = 16.dp,
                        vertical = 4.dp,
                    )
                    .background(colors[it % colors.size])
                    .height(80.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: only thing to improve in this answer is move list outside of the composable function to prevent redraw allocations